# Condition on all rows of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

Concerning this type of dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
                   'Time': [datetime.date(2019, 12, 1), datetime.date(2019, 12, 5),datetime.date(2019, 12, 8),datetime.date(2019, 8, 4),datetime.date(2019, 11, 4),datetime.date(2019, 11, 4),datetime.date(2019, 11, 3),datetime.date(2019, 12, 20)],
                   'Value':[2,2,2,50,7,100,7,5]})
```

```
    ID  Time        Value
0   1   2019-12-01  2
1   1   2019-12-05  2
2   1   2019-12-08  2
3   1   2019-08-04  50
4   2   2019-11-04  7
5   2   2019-11-04  100
6   2   2019-11-03  7
7   3   2019-12-20  5
```

I am intersted only in the 3 latest values (regarding the time)

and

I would like to keep only the IDs where these 3 values are < 10.

So my desired output will look like this:

```
    ID
0   1
```

Indeed the value 50 for the first ID is the fourth last value, so it's not interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a groupby:

- I sort the group by time
- use a boolean to determine if the condition <10 is satisfied or not
- Take the last 3 values only and sum the boolean defined above
- Check if this number is exactly 3

```py
grp = df.groupby("ID")\
        .apply(lambda x: 
         x.sort_values("Time")["Value"].lt(10)[-3:].sum()==3)

grp[grp]
```

```sh
ID
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of `query` and `groupby`+`size`:

```
ids = df.query('Value < 10').groupby('ID')['Time'].size().ge(3)
ids[ids].reset_index().drop('Time', axis=1)
```

output:

```
   ID
0   1
```

Alternative using `filter` (slower):

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: len(g[g['Value'].lt(10)]['Time'].nlargest(3))>2)
```

output:

```
   ID       Time  Value
0   1 2019-12-01      2
1   1 2019-12-05      2
2   1 2019-12-08      2
3   1 2019-08-04     50
```

and to get only the ID: add `['ID'].unique()`

Comment: Am I wrong or filtering before take the greatest time it could return wrong results?

Comment: I understood the question as *we need at least 3 values below 10*, if this is not correct, then it's quite easy to use the same logic with a different condition

Comment: Indeed @rpanai, we would like to look only at the 3 latest values, so if you remove the values under the condition it will not work ... but thanks for your help for now !

Comment: @mozway on the OP it says `3 latest values`. I was confused too.

Comment: ok, then the two conditions need to be swapped (first take the 3 latest, then remove the values, finally count), but the overall logic is similar ;)